# Where is the super reference in a Java instance method's stack frame?

Tags: java, reference, jvm, stack, super

I read Bill Venner's excellent Inside the Java Virtual Machine book, which, in Chapter 5 explores in detail, among other things, the composition of a JVM's stack frame.
(This chapter from the book also happens to be officially published here: https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm8.html)
Apart from this book I studied relatively much the runtime data areas of some JVM's, especially their stack and heap.

In an instance method's stack frame, the local variables section constitutes an array of words which holds the **method arguments** (or parameters), **local variables** and the "hidden" **this reference**.

What I'd like to know is, **where is the super reference stored**, as that is *also always available in any non-static context* (i.e. instance method body or initializer block), except in the Object class. Is it stored somewhere alongside the reference "this"? If yes, then why is it seemingly always left out from stack frame representations/overviews?

Comment: `super()` is a way of referencing methods defined in this object's inheritance hierarchy. The inheritance hierarchy is part of the class whose instance is referenced by `this`.

Comment: I was referring to the reference and not the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "super" reference.

When you do:

```
super.foo()
```

You "seem" to be calling `foo` on an object called "super", but that's merely Java's syntax, and doesn't have to reflect what's happening under the hood. When this call is translated, it is translated to a [`invokespecial`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial) instruction, that invokes the superclass's `foo` method.

Compare this to a `this.foo()` call, which translates to a [`invokevirtual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) instruction. Unlike `invokespecial`, this will do dynamic dispatch, selecting the right method to call, depending on the runtime type of `this`.

Note that in both cases, there is a `aload_0` instruction before invoking the method, loading the `this` reference onto the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The 'hidden this' reference does not exist in they way you think.

If you call `super.toString()`, then `super` is resolved and stored to 'hidden this'.
So once the stack frame of `runInstanceMethod()` - in our example `toString()` - is created, the 'hidden this' *IS* the former super.

In other words, the 'hidden this' always refers to the object that the current member method belongs to.